# Protractor's mouseMove() unsupported for geckodriver firefox

Tags: angularjs, angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

Is there any alternative for protractor's mouseMove? I would like the mouse to hover over the menu. But it appears to be unsupported with geckodriver.

So far I've tried, browser.executeScript('arguments[0].mouseMove()', element(by.className('menu')));

But get this error, Failed: TypeError: arguments[0].mouseOver is not a function.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it :) Thanks for your help.

Here's what I found worked,

`browser.executeScript(
      'return arguments[0].click();',
       browser.driver.findElement(by.className('menu')));`

Answer (score 0):

There are two error usage in your script.

**Firstly**, Protractor `element()` api return an ElementFinder which is a wrapper upon HTML Web Element.  But the `arguments[0]` in `arguments[0].mouseMove()` require a HTML Web Element. This rule is apply to all browser, not only required by Firefox.

You need to call `getWebElement()` on ElementFinder to get the Web Element as below.

**Secondly**, HTML Web Element does not has the `mouseMove()` api, but `mousemove` event.

```
browser.executeScript(
    // web element not has mouseMove() api,
    // so below usage is wrong.
    'return arguments[0].mouseMove();', 
    element(by.className('menu')).getWebElement()
);
```

Comment: Hi @yong, thanks for your reply. I tried the following, `browser.executeScript(
      'return arguments[0].mousemove;',
       menuArea.getWebElement());` But it doesn't appear to hover over the menu icon as intended. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks :)